# Character Array User Input Scanf

Tags: c

Just started learning programming on my own and whilst trying to create an array of characters from user input, using scanf, have hit the wall; the code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define I 5

int main (void) {

    char a[I+1] = {a[I+1] = '\0'}, q;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < I; i++) {
        printf("Enter an alphabet:\t");
        //scanf("%c", &q);
        //scanf("%c*\n", &q);
        //scanf("%[^\n]", &q);
        //scanf("%[a-z, A-Z]", &q);
        scanf("%127[^\n]", &q);
        a[i] = q;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < I; i++)  {
        printf("Element a[%d] of a[I]:\t%c\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("And the a[I] string:\t%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

None of the scanf combinations in the above code works: the program either skips input prompt after the first one or does not store response.

How can this be resolved with scanf?

Comment: `char a[I+1] = {a[I+1] = '\0'}, q;` is an error, if you do not see an error message then please adjust your compiler settings as you are missing out on important information

Comment: also can you explain how you imagine to store 127 characters of input in the single character `q` ?

Answer (score 0):

`char a[I+1] = {a[I+1] = '\0'}` is not valid. Even if it compiles, it is going out of bounds when assigning the `'\0'` character.  The commonly used convention looks more like this instead:

```
char a[I+1] = {0};
```

Or simply:

```
char a[I+1] = {};
```

That said, `q` is only 1 `char` in size, but your `scanf()` is trying to read a string up to 127 `char`s into `q`.  So you are going to trash memory.  To read a single `char` at a time, use `%c` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT 5

int main (void) {

    char a[MAX_INPUT+1];
    int i, len;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_INPUT; i++) {
        printf("Enter an alphabet:\t");
        scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    }
    a[MAX_INPUT] = '\0';

    printf("\n");

    len = strlen(a);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)  {
        printf("Element a[%d]:\t%c\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("And the a string:\t%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you can remove the loop and just use a single call to `scanf()` using `"%5[^\n]"` as the format string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT 5

int main (void) {

    char a[MAX_INPUT+1];
    char fmt[20];
    int i, len;

    sprintf(fmt, "%%%d[^\n]", MAX_INPUT);

    printf("Enter an alphabet:\t");
    scanf(fmt, a);

    printf("\n");

    len = strlen(a);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)  {
        printf("Element a[%d]:\t%c\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("And the a string:\t%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Caan I have fixed them

Comment: [Screenshot_2 for 1st Solution](https://prnt.sc/lttf90) &  [Screenshot_2 for 2nd Solution](https://prnt.sc/lttgfd)

Comment: @Caan the first solution does not discard the newline typed after each character, so it carries into the next read. What are you trying to point out about the second solution? The screenshot is not descriptive. To read a line of text on one go, use `fgets()` or `getline()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: The 2nd solution just hangs after 1st response at the point as in in the screenshot.

Comment: @Caan `"%5[^\\n]"` should be `"%5[^\n]"`. But also see [Why won't this scanf format-string work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255891/)

Comment: The `{}` initializer is not valid in C; it probably is valid in modern C++.  You omitted the traditional `""` which also works, with or without the enclosing braces.

Answer (score -1):

This works without any warning or error on Cygwin gcc v7.3 with Wall flag:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define I 5

int main (void) {
    char a[I+1] = {a[I+1] = '\0'},q;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < I; i++) {
        printf("Enter an alphabet:\t");
        scanf("%c%*c", &q);
        a[i] = q;
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < I; i++)  {
        printf("Element a[%d] of a[I]:\t%c\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    printf("And the string a[I]:\t%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's curious.  I saved the code above into a file `ok59.c`.  Compiling it on a Mac with GCC 7.3.0 (`/opt/gcc/v7.3.0/bin/gcc -O3   -g  -std=c11 -Wall  -Werror ok59.c -o ok59`, I get the message: `ok59.c: In function ‘main’:
ok59.c:5:21: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]` pointing at `char a[I+1] = {a[I+1] = '\0'},q;`.  Granted, this is not Cygwin, but…I get the message with `-std=c90` too.  (Not my DV.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I've tried the same flags as in your comment and it compiled without any warning or error. Any idea why the response is different when code and flags are the same?

Comment: Frankly, no — I'm surprised.