# how to put an option like this " try again? Y/N"?

Tags: c

I have been trying to put an option that would ask the user to try again or not, but I was unsuccessful in doing that. How do I do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int largest(int[], int);
int main()
{
    char repeat;
    int arr[5];
    int i;

    while (repeat == "y" || "Y")
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("\nInput a number at index %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
        printf("Largest in given array is %d\n", largest(arr, 5));
    }
}
int largest(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to actually set `repeat` to some value. Where do you even attempt to read into or set that variable? Secondly `==` cannot be used for comparing strings rather use `strcmp`. Thirdly, `repeat` is not a string but just a single char.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `repeat` to 'y' so it will go through the `while` loop at least once:

```
char repeat = 'y';
```

Your `while` loop needs to change to:

```
while (repeat == 'y'  ||  repeat == 'Y') {
```

Then as the last thing in your `while` loop, after the `printf`, you'll want something like this:

```
printf("\nTry again? (Y/N) ");
scanf(" %c%*[^\n]",&repeat);
```

Comment: See [Why won't this scanf format-string work? `"%[^\n]\n"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35255891/3422102)