why second five digits are not showing?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a,b,c,d,e;
int f,g,h,i,j;

int add1;
int s;
int add2;
int operation1;
int subtraction;
int Remainder;
int checkdigit;

int main()
{
    printf("Enter First Six Digits :-");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d " , &s , &a , &b, &c , &d , &e);

    printf("Enter Second Five Digits :-");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d" , &f , &g , &h , &i , &j);

    add1 = s + b + d + f + h + j ;
    add2 = a + c + e + g + i ;

    operation1 = ((3*add1) + add2);
    subtraction = (operation1 - 1);
    Remainder = subtraction%10 ;
    checkdigit = (9 - Remainder);
    printf("Bar code Check digit :- %d " , checkdigit);
}

So when I try to run this program, my screen only shows the first six digits; when I put the value, I do not get the first five digits message. So where I went wrong I do not get any errors when I try to run this program.

Welcome to SO. To make your question readable, please apply some decent formatting. Without excessive blank lines and included in lines that only contain \```.

Not causing your problem, but you should not use global variables unless there is a good reason for it. In your code, there is no such reason. You could (and should) declare all these variables within main function. And you should get used to always check return value of scanf and related functions. If you do not check the return value, you will never detect if incorrect input was provided.

Follow on to @Gerhardh's comment: always check the return value from scanf.

Rather than tell us about your erroneous output, show us.

You might not see all your output because stdout normally is line buffered. To make everything appear on the screen, add a \n at the end of your printf string or use fflush(stdout) before you call scanf.

Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255891/why-wont-this-scanf-format-string-work-n-n

Possibly a duplicate of: What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?


So when I try to run this program, my screen only shows the first six digits; when I put the value, I do not get the first five digits message.

That's because the first scanf is still waiting for you to complete your input.  In particular, it's still trying to match the trailing whitespace in the scanf format, which matches an arbitrary number of whitespace characters, including newlines.  scanf doesn't know it's done matching whitespace until it sees non-whitespace or the end of the file, but you're waiting to provide any such input until you get the next prompt, which won't be issued until the scanf returns.
You should remove the tailing whitespace in that format. That will not affect the next scanf() because %d, like almost all conversion specifiers, automatically skips leading whitespace (the exceptions that don't do that are %c, %n, and %[).  That means you could also remove the internal whitespace in your formats, though I personally like it for readability.
Side note:
You are prompting for digits, but each %d in your format will successfully read and convert at least any decimal integer within the range of type int, including those with many digits.  That may be ok with you, but it could produce unexpected results if your input does not meet your expectations.

Note also that the return value from scanf should be checked, and scanning for 5 or 6 values in one call to scanf makes it harder to handle errors. I would suggest all of those variables be an array, and then use a loop to read them in. That way each input can be checked as it's input and if erroneous input is encountered, it can be handled.

ok so i understand your explanation , but one thing i do not understand is that when i try to run this program i got message ENTER FIRST SIX DIGIT so when i put digits i do not understand why scanf is not considering the whole digits as a single int number. is it because i put space between each digits? please clear my confusion related to this?

Yes, @arnold, each %d will match a run of decimal digits, optionally preceded by a - sign. When it sees anything else, including, but not limited to, a space character, it interprets that as the start of some yet-to-be-determined other input.  Note well that that behavior belongs to %d alone -- it has nothing in particular to do with whatever, if anything, follows it in the format string.
